# Rework signing of Text with only Public Keys

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Trying to rework a solution without  re-compiling my application
I have an application that reads a configuration file that has a signed component and the application  verifies
that the content is legit with code below. The issue I have is that there is a Service that signs the original document and no one has the source code of this running Service and having issues with service and I'd like to recreate locally but I don't have the entire RSA key. Not knowing a great deal of RSA encryption - I don't think I can re-create the RSA key from the modulus and exponent that I have - is that correct ?

One option and not sure is possible - is it feasible to create a new RSA key using the exponent and modulus that I have and encrypt new configuration files with the new key ? This way I can verify old and new config files with modulus and exponent used by both keys and and build encryption program with the new key and maintain the source ?

```
RSAParameters pms = new RSAParameters(); 
pms.Exponent = exponent;
pms.Modulus = modulus; 
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); 
provider.ImportParameters(pms); 
//signature is Signed String to compare to current config
bool result = provider.VerifyData(config_bytes, new MD5CryptoServiceProvider(), signature);
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: It is unclear to me what you try to archive and what key is missing. Your title says "signing", in your question you write more than one time "encryption" and your code is about signing again. So what key is missing? When reading between the lines you already have a RSA **public key** but there is no way to derive/get a **private** key from the public key. But when you are been able to verify the configuration file that was signed with an "old/lost" private key with the available public key - why don't you sign the data again with a new RSA key pair and throw away the old signatures?

Comment: The way to retrieve the old private key is through reverse engineering the existing service. The difficulty of that task can vary from relatively easy to very painfully tedious depending on the details. As @MichaelFehr stated, you can't get the private key from the public, you can't create a new private key that works with the public key, and the interfaces that .Net provides for signing don't give you a way to get the private key either.

Comment: @MichaelFehr - throwing away and starting anew is an option - I will need to recompile my application and distribute with new key verification - To avoid recompiling is the reason why I was asking to create a new key with the 2 parts I have. This way I can resign new file but not recompile my application because it would share the 2 know parts of the rsa for verification of signature